# How is initiative affected by dice pool modifiers?

Tags: spells, shadowrun-sr5, initiative

Initiative rolls do not generate hits, so how are the dice pool modifiers from sustained spells subtracted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no rules stating that there is any effect on initiative so there is none.

Core Rulebook, p. 282

> If you sustain the spell [...], you take a -2 dice pool penalty to all tests while it is sustained.

Sustained spells don't affect initiative. You don't use a dice pool for initiative and it's not a test either.

You can act just as fast while sustaining spells but if you do anything that requires a test, you're less effective.

Similarly your base carrying capacity is not affected, but if you want to carry more doing a \$BOD + STR\$ test, you'd suffer the negative effects of sustaining spells for this test.